# Umerge table cell in InDesign bug

Tags: adobe-indesign, tables, merge, cell

This is really weird and annoying: When I unmerge table cell, all the below rows go away with remain unfit in frame, but Fit to Frame do not work.

I tried to create new column, and removed the column with merged cell — but result is the same — all the below rows go away, and I can't access them in any way — also tried to decrease the rows heights.

When I remove any other column, everything is fine!! :(

Anyone faced something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've found a way out. Still don't know what was the cause and what would be the easier way to fix this.

I've used the '+' button to create another frame with the rest of the content. Then somehow I am not sure what happened next, but in the end I just extended the initial table frame and everything transferred back.

Comment: The red + indicates *"more content which won't fit in this frame"*. You simply needed to increase the size of the text frame. The red + **always** means something is cut off.